# write phrase(String) in another program with robot method in java

Tags: java, macos, awtrobot

Hi i want to write a program that should write a phrase in another program(i mean for example i want to open TextEdit  and write a phrase).
I know how to open  another program

```
File file = new File("/Applications/TextEdit.app");
Desktop.getdesktop().open(file);
```

and I know how to press a key in keyboard with robot method

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keypress(KeyEvent.VK_G)
```

As you can see this code write a letter not phrase
and the big problem is this method does not support the ASCII code.

for example if the ASCII code of  'a'  is 98, when i write 98 as the parameter into Robot methos

```
robot.keypress(98);
```

it print another letter.

so what should i do to write a phrase in another program with java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done for a given character assuming that your OS is Mac OS:

```
char c = 'a';
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    char current = Integer.toHexString((c & 15 << (4 * i)) >> (4 * i)).charAt(0);
    int keyCode;
    switch (current) {
        case 'a':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_A;
            break;
        case 'b':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_B;
            break;
        case 'c':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_C;
            break;
        case 'd':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_D;
            break;
        case 'e':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_E;
            break;
        case 'f':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_F;
            break;
        case '0':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_0;
            break;
        case '1':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_1;
            break;
        case '2':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_2;
            break;
        case '3':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_3;
            break;
        case '4':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_4;
            break;
        case '5':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_5;
            break;
        case '6':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_6;
            break;
        case '7':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_7;
            break;
        case '8':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_8;
            break;
        case '9':
            keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_9;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected character: " + current);
    }
    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
}
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```